# Making the WebView more little

Tags: iphone, ios, uiwebview

I have a little app for the iPad that shows some things, and a little WebView. The problem is that I don't know how to make the webs that the WebView shows more little. Anyone knows something about it?

Comment: More little? You're going to have to be more specific about (1) what you have done and (2) what you want to see.

Comment: Do you mean make the WebView content smaller? That would likely be controlled by the website (it should detect that the device is an iPad or iPhone and have a special mobile version of the website that has a  layout suitable for a mobile device).

Answer (score 4):

You may want to tell the `UIWebView` to scale the page to its bounds and modify its frame to the size you want.

```
 [webView setScalesPageToFit:YES];
 [webView setFrame:yourFrame];
```

Comment: But just one more thing: yourFrame what a type of data has to be?

Comment: A `CGRect`– you can use `CGRectMake(x, y, width, height);` to create it.

Comment: it isn't over yet. I make all, and it doesn't make what I want. I want the images, the text, and all in the WebView be more little. For example,I want to make this text more little, but not just the text, all the web page, all displayed in the UIWebView. Your code doesn't make it.

Comment: It's not over till it's over. Have you tried using a smaller frame?

Comment: Yes... don't worry, thank you for your help, I will try to solve this on my own.